# how to access the function from console inside of build/main.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, global-variables

I'm using ionic/Angular and I can't seem to have access to the functions that's inside of the webpack built js file. when I open chrome console and type in the function nothing happens.. I tried window.myfunction() in typescript but it didn't like the window.

Comment: Your functions probably aren't in the window scope, they are inside their own modules with local scope, anonymous to the window.

Comment: How would I make it globally visible, I've been stuck on this for 2 days T.T

Comment: In your source code you can always do something like `window.myFunction = this.myFunction`,or make an entire class available by `window.app = this.app`, and then you can call `window.app.myFunction()`. I have no idea what will happen if you try this with an Angular app though! Perhaps it's better to write a specific test class if your goal is debugging.

Comment: If you don't want to use Modules, don't use them. If you do want to use them, learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to simulate push notifications is, in the constructor, exporting to the global window my App class

```
export class MyApp {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    window["myapp"] = this; //<-- export the class into window
  }

  onNotification(data) {
    //processNotification
  }
}
```

Then using the console I can simulate receiving a notification:

> window.myapp.onNotification({additionalData:{type:"test", foreground:true}, message:"This is the message"})

I hope it helps